# .NET Core System.InvalidOperationException: Instance failure

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

When connecting EF Core to a local SQL Express instance I'm suddenly seeing the following error -

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Instance failure.
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)...
```

The connection string is coming from my appsettings.json file -

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings:DefaultDatabase": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;User ID=sqluser;Password=password;"
}
```

I'm accessing the configuration like so -

```
public void InitializeContainer(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var db = configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStrings:DefaultDatabase");

    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(db));
}
```

I know the reason I'm seeing this error is because the string is being escaped, so my variable ends up looking like this `Server=.\\\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=CustomerContact;Trusted_Connection=True;User ID=swwdev;Password=password;`.

Fine, but how do I get around this? If I change `appsettings.json` to a single `\` I get another error saying the JSON is invalid. I can't understand what has changed as it was working up until recently.

Comment: _"I know the reason I'm seeing this error is because the string is being escaped"_ - no, it's not. That's the debugger displaying you escaped strings. The string itself is fine, and reading it works as well. It's definitely a problem with your SQL Server instance. Is it running? Can you connect through SSMS?

Comment: The SQL instance is definitely working as if I replace the `db` variable with the hard coded connection string it works!

Comment: @ChrisEdgington your config key doesn't match your JSON file. You're reading the wrong connection string (there's no `ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStrings:DefaultDatabase`). This JSON config file is weird to say the least. If you want to use the `ConnectionStrings` *section*, it has to be a proper section. If it is, you can use `configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultDatabase")`. If you *don't* want that section, there's no reason to use `ConnectionStrings:DefaultDatabase` as the name. You could call it `Potato` and retrieve it with `configuration.GetValue<string>("Potato")`.

Answer (score 0):

Both the appsettings.json file and the configuration code have problems.

Change your connection string section to this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=False;User ID=...;Password=...;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096;"
}
....
```

and your startup file :

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

.....
var connString=Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connString));
```

Comment: No, appSettings get folded using colons, OP's syntax works. Using `configuration.GetValue<string>("Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft")` will also work and return `Warning`.

Comment: `"DefaultConnection":Data Source` that's invalid JSON. The OP's (assumed) problem is the use of `.\SQLExpress`. This isn't a question on how to write a connection string or how to register a DbContext

Comment: I repeat again - I used it in  dozens of ef core applications and never had any invalid json errors.

Comment: And I used it in hundreds, it works, but that doesn't explain how this solves the OP's problem. Is the appsettings file problematic? Yes. Does the OP's code read the wrong connection string? Yes. How can this be fixed? This is the answer